Are there term symbols for non-diatomic molecules?
Term symbols help summarize the various angular momenta of an atom or molecule.
The term symbol for atoms is generally written ${}^{2S+1}L_{J}$.
The term symbol for diatomic molecules is generally written ${}^{2S+1}\Lambda_{\Omega,(g/u)}^{(+/-)}$.
Is there an equivalent term symbol for molecules with more than two atoms? Or is that meaningless as you start to get multiple inter-nuclear axes?

There are term symbols for the electronic states of nonlinear molecules. For example, the ground state of $\ce{NO2}$ is $^2\mathrm{A}_1$. Here the "$2$" means doublet and is $2S+1$ as usual ($\ce{NO2}$ has an unpaired electron). The $\mathrm{A}_1$ is the labelling for the symmetry species, which is one of the irreducible representations of the molecular point group, which in this case is $C_{2\mathrm{v}}$, i.e., the molecule is bent in the ground state. So $\mathrm{A}_1$ describes the symmetry of the electronic state (depending on all the molecular orbitals).
The 5th excited state of $\ce{NO2}$ is $^2\Sigma_u^+$, which tells you it is linear. Linear molecules, including diatomics, are in the $D_{\infty\mathrm{h}}$ (as in this case) or $C_{\infty\mathrm{v}}$ point groups. So although the base of the term symbol for linear molecules tells something about the angular momentum, it is also a symmetry label. For nonlinear molecules, the angular momentum is not useful, but the symmetry is.
